# Arabic language localization in a english desktop C#.net application

Tags: c#, .net, localization, arabic

I am building an enterprise C#.net application, the requirement is there will be Arabic and English version both. 2 options are given from client, either to write English plus Arabic together for labels and descriptions or to place a combo box in start having English and Arabic to select and to proceed with that language.
I want to save my time and want that i could just build an English version and Arabic must be auto translated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking for a pony.  Well, mechanical turk.  Localization is well supported in .NET but you don't give any hint what kind of GUI you use.  Silverlight, ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF, it matters.  You also cannot ignore that Arabic is rendered right-to-left.

Comment: By desktop you mean standard WinForms, right?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you do not need to select anything, it would be already selected if somebody set Arabic Locale in his/her Operating System. To detect what language is used (if you need this information, usually you don't) you would simply read `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` property.

However, in WinForms you could actually use built-in Localization support. To do that, you need to switch Form `Localizable` property to true. Assuming that you have Arabic strings provided, you would need to switch Form's `Language` property from (default) to Arabic **after** you complete you English layout and place the translations in appropriate places. That is the easiest way. You would also need to switch Form's `RightToLeft` property to Yes and `RightToLeftLayout` to True while on Arabic.
If you do that properly, you would see that form is mirrored. That's desired situation, do not panic.

The worse part is that you would occasionally need to display Message Boxes. The problem here is, that depending on what language type you are using, you actually would need to do it in a different way, for Arabic (and other RTL languages) require that RTLReading constant be used:

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)
{
    MessageBox.Show(text, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(text, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

That's it on the high level...

Answer (score 4):

you can use 2 resource files one in English and one in Arabic and when you select the language the application selects what resource file to use.

Comment: how to use that and can i download it?

Comment: you can add a resource file and edit it(visual studio has template)

Comment: does it have any option to auto convert all labels and translate it into arabic?