# how to change the language of opendialog in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, opendialog

i write a program and wnat to get the opendialog that open in my language
i try to change culture ui but it doesn't cahnge the english layout
can someone know how to change it?

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995015/arabic-language-localization-in-a-english-desktop-c-net-application

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy 
this is good extended OFD

Answer (score 9):

OpenFileDialog is a wrapper for a native Windows dialog.  You'll also see it when you use Notepad's File + Open command for example.

All native Windows windows are localized by the resource tables that are built into Windows itself.  They are quite large, about half a gigabyte of disk storage.  The user will get the ones that match the language version of Windows.  So, say, a German user will have obtained the German language version of Windows and gets the resource tables for German.

So, you'll always get to see the strings that match your native language version.  The Thread.CurrentUICulture property has no effect.  This never confuses a user.

If you need localized dialogs to make screenshots for example then you need to obtain the localized Windows version, you can get them with an MSDN subscription.  Or you can obtain a license to the English version of Windows Ultimate.  Which supports downloadable language packs which supports switching languages.  You do so by changing the Language in the Control Panel's Region applet.