# C# FileDialogs aren't localized

Tags: c#, file, localization, dialog, locale

I have a OpenFileDialog and a SaveFileDialog in my C# program. However, they are always shown at English instead of Windows language.

I want them to be shown at Windows current language, like other programs do.

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileName = dialog.FileName;
    //Process file...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arabic language localization in a english desktop C#.net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995015/arabic-language-localization-in-a-english-desktop-c-net-application)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Do you have something that changes the CurrentCulture of your application?

Comment: Maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619690/how-to-change-the-language-of-opendialog-in-winforms) it is the answer you are looking for

Comment: @Steve I don't have something like that.

Comment: @meJustAndrew From your link:

"All native Windows windows are localized by the resource tables that are built into Windows itself. The user will get the ones that match the language version of Windows."

This doesn't happen in my program.