# Change defaut text on a save button

Tags: c#, windows, button, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

It's my first message here and I'm not a native English speaker so thank you in advance for not minding to much about my mistakes.

My problem is that I want to change the default text of a `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` because in my application there is an option to change the language settings.
The buttons texts are "Save" and "Open".

I can do it for other buttons thanks to the `MessageBoxManager`, however I need to do it also for the button "Save" and for the button "Open".

Those buttons have to be handled by other means, because I can't find their "ID" (`ID_ok = 1`, `ID_cancel = 2`) and I can't find "Save".
So if you have any idea for a solution I will be very grateful.

---

```
#pragma warning disable 0618
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, UnmanagedCode = true)]
namespace System.Windows.Forms {
    public class MessageBoxManager {
        private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private delegate bool EnumChildProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        private const int WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12;
        private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
        private const int WM_INITDIALOG = 0x0110;
        private const int WM_TIMER = 0x0113;
        private const int WM_USER = 0x400;
        private const int DM_GETDEFID = WM_USER + 0;

        private const int MBOK = 1;
        private const int MBCancel = 2;
        private const int MBAbort = 3;
        private const int MBRetry = 4;
        private const int MBIgnore = 5;
        private const int MBYes = 6;
        private const int MBNo = 7;
        private const int MBSave = 8;


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowTextLengthW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowTextW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int maxLength);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int EndDialog(IntPtr hDlg, IntPtr nResult);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndParent, EnumChildProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassNameW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetDlgCtrlID(IntPtr hwndCtl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hDlg, int nIDDlgItem);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowTextW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CWPRETSTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr lResult;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public uint   message;
            public IntPtr hwnd;
         };

        private static HookProc hookProc;
        private static EnumChildProc enumProc;
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static IntPtr hHook;
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static int nButton;

        /// <summary>
        /// OK text
        /// </summary>
        public static string OK = "&OK";
        /// <summary>
        /// Cancel text
        /// </summary>
        public static string Cancel = "&Cancel";
        /// <summary>
        /// Abort text
        /// </summary>
        public static string Abort = "&Abort";
        /// <summary>
        /// Retry text
        /// </summary>
        public static string Retry = "&Retry";
        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore text
        /// </summary>
        public static string Ignore = "&Ignore";
        /// <summary>
        /// Yes text
        /// </summary>
        public static string Yes = "&Yes";
        /// <summary>
        /// No text
        /// </summary>
        public static string No = "&No";
        /// No text
        /// </summary>
        public static string Save = "&Save";


    static MessageBoxManager()
    {
        hookProc = new HookProc(MessageBoxHookProc);
        enumProc = new EnumChildProc(MessageBoxEnumProc);
        hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables MessageBoxManager functionality
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// MessageBoxManager functionality is enabled on current thread only.
    /// Each thread that needs MessageBoxManager functionality has to call this method.
    /// </remarks>
    public static void Register()
    {
        if (hHook != IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new NotSupportedException("One hook per thread allowed.");
        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disables MessageBoxManager functionality
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Disables MessageBoxManager functionality on current thread only.
    /// </remarks>
    public static void Unregister()
    {
        if (hHook != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
            hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr MessageBoxHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

        CWPRETSTRUCT msg = (CWPRETSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CWPRETSTRUCT));
        IntPtr hook = hHook;

        if (msg.message == WM_INITDIALOG)
        {
            int nLength = GetWindowTextLength(msg.hwnd);
            StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(10);
            GetClassName(msg.hwnd, className, className.Capacity);
            if (className.ToString() == "#32770")
            {
                nButton = 0;
                EnumChildWindows(msg.hwnd, enumProc, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (nButton == 1)
                {
                    IntPtr hButton = GetDlgItem(msg.hwnd, MBCancel);
                    if (hButton != IntPtr.Zero)
                        SetWindowText(hButton, OK);
                }
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static bool MessageBoxEnumProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(10);
        GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity);
        if (className.ToString() == "Button")
        {
            int ctlId = GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd);
            switch (ctlId)
            {
                case MBOK:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, OK);
                    break;
                case MBCancel:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Cancel);
                    break;
                case MBAbort:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Abort);
                    break;
                case MBRetry:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Retry);
                    break;
                case MBIgnore:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Ignore);
                    break;
                case MBYes:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Yes);
                    break;
                case MBNo:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, No);
                    break;
                case MBSave:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Save);
                    break;
                case 1038:
                    SetWindowText(hWnd, Retry);
                    break;
            }
            nButton++;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit:
First, thank to correct my mistakes (many of them) ^^.... The reason, I want translate the button is simple. My program have to be translate in 5 languages that can be selected by the menu. I don't have "window ultimate" to change the setting language like i want.

But anyway, I don't want change the language of the OS at every click. i had only two solutions create all messageBox and openDialog by myself and change the 1500 times where the program call messageBox.show by my new form (what will spend many time...) or translate the buttons correctly for messageBox and open/save dialogBox. The computer used is dedied for this program, no any others programs should be used.

Currently I'm able to translate all messageBox correctly, But my problem is for the Buttons "save", "open"(this text change like my button "ok") if you want i can tell you where you can dowload the project to have a better idea of the fonction realized

Comment: Let me ask: why do you _worry_ to translate system message box? If they have a localized Windows version then they'll get proper text...

Comment: I don't think that you have to search for a button on standard dialog to change a text to maintain translation on other languages, because Windows will translate all the texts of all dialogs in system by itself, according to installed system language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arabic language localization in a english desktop C#.net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995015/arabic-language-localization-in-a-english-desktop-c-net-application)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That would follow the *operating system* language, not the OP's program language.

Comment: @Alejandro true but that's a **pain**. Windows dialogs change. To keep in sync with them (and with Windows versions) is tricky (and requires extra effort). An half localized dialog is horrible (at best). 99.99% of times users have Windows on their own language (of course if Windows has a localized version for that language). When this isn't true...they're used to see them in the OS language in every other program...anyway...